# Python Class "Main" Value

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and have been writing a code that will read and write from a binary file.

I decided to create classes for every type of data that will be contained within the file, and to keep them organized I made one class they would all inherit, called InteriorIO. I want each class to have a read and write method which would read/write the data to/from the file. At the same time as inheriting InteriorIO however, I want them to behave like str or int in that they return the value they contain, so I'd modify either `__str__` or `__int__` depending on what they most closely resemble.

```
class InteriorIO(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def read(this, f):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def write(this, f):
        pass

class byteIO(InteriorIO):
    def __init__(this, value=None):
        this.value = value

    def read(this, f):
        this.value = struct.unpack("B", f.read(1))[0]

    def __str__:
        return value;

class U16IO(InteriorIO):
    def __init__(this, value=None):
        this.value = value

    def read(this, f):
        this.value = struct.unpack("<H", f.read(2))[0]

    def __int__:
        return value;

# how I'd like it to work
f.open("C:/some/path/file.bin")
# In the file, the fileVersion is a U16
fileVersion = U16IO()
# We read the value from the file, storing it in fileVersion
fileVersion.read(f)
# writes the fileVersion that was just read from the file
print(str(fileVersion))
# now let's say we want to write the number 35 to the file in the form of a U16, so we store the value 35 in valueToWrite
valueToWrite = U16IO(35)
# prints the value 35
print(valueToWrite)
# writes the number 35 to the file
valueToWrite.write(f)
f.close()
```

The code on the bottom works, but the classes feel wrong and too ambiguous. I'm setting `this.value`, which is a random name I came up with, for every object as a sort of "main" value, and then returning said value as the type I want it to be.

What is the cleanest way to organize my classes such that they all inherit from InteriorIO, yet behave like a str or int in that they return their value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in that case you may want to consider the [Factory Design Pattern](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1099559).

Here is a simple example to explain the idea:

```
class Cup:
    color = ""

    # This is the factory method
    @staticmethod
    def getCup(cupColor, value):
        if (cupColor == "red"):
            return RedCup(value)
        elif (cupColor == "blue"):
            return BlueCup(value)
        else:
            return None

class RedCup(Cup):
    color = "Red"

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


class BlueCup(Cup):
    color = "Blue"

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

# A little testing
redCup = Cup.getCup("red", 10)
print("{} ({})".format(redCup.color, redCup.__class__.__name__))

blueCup = Cup.getCup("blue", 20)
print("{} ({})".format(blueCup.color, blueCup.__class__.__name__))
```

So you have a factory `Cup` which contains a static method `getCup` which given a value, will decide which object to "generate" hence the title "factory".

Then in your code you only need to call the factory's `getCup` method and this will return you back with the appropriate class to work with.

They way to deal with `__int__` and `__str__` I think in the classes where you are missing either, just implement it and return back None. So your U16IO should implement a `__str__` method that return `None` and your byteIO should implement a `__int__` that also return `None`.

Comment: How could I pass in a value to RedCup/BlueCup, like what I did with U16IO to write a value I already knew?

Comment: @tomysshadow Your `RedCup` and `BlueCup` can still have constructors (i.e `__init__`) which can still accept parameters. Can the value passed to the factory method determined the class to create? My above example (taken from the reference I have added) is a minimal one, that doesn't mean you can't have constructors and parameters passing to them

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the case with constructor and extra value need to be passed into it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you even using classes here? It seems overly complicated.

You could just define two functions, `read` and `write`;

```
def bread(format, binaryfile):
    return struct.unpack(format, binaryfile.read(format.calcsize()))

def bwrite(format, binaryfile, *args):
    binaryfile.write(struct.pack(format, *args))
```

Comment: It's because I also have more complex classes which take in two or three values instead of just one.

Comment: @tomysshadow The `bread` function should already handle that use-case. I've changed `bwrite` to handle it as well.